# useAuth0().user doesn't show the user Roles

Tags: reactjs, jwt, auth0

I am having issues to get a Auth0 user Roles when I call the `useAuth0().user` react hook.

At the moment I am getting this:

```
    email: "myemail@test.com"
    email_verified: true
    name: "BB"
    nickname: "BB"
    picture: "https://..."
    sub: "auth0|ABC123"
    updated_at: "2021-02-17T17:24:17.989Z"
```

In the Auth0 dashboard, I have my user setup with an 'Admin' role and I am trying to set 'Rules' in order to pass the 'app_metadata' to the API response.
I have seen a bunch of scripts to get the Rules, but none of them works.

`context.authorization.roles`, tested in the Auth0 create `Rules` test script window, always returns undefined.
I am wondering if I am entering the namespace attached to the tokenID incorrectly. At the moment is the URL of the dev page I am using to access to login page. Is that correct? (https://dev-fkjer8938 etc....).

In theory I should be able to see:

```
"app_metadata": {
    "roles": [
        "admin"
    ]
},
```

Your help is much appreciated.
Joe

Comment: Are you using the Authorization Extension or the Roles from "Users & Roles"?

Comment: @Ben From the Users & Roles.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will be an exact answer, but some things for consideration which might help:

When you assign roles to a user, they'll show up on the tokens depending on how you explicitly add them. I'm not sure they will be accessible via the `useAuth0().user` as [from the documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login#show-user-profile-information) it looks like that's more for user/profile metadata. You might instead need to use `getAccessTokenSilently` ([also from the `useAuth0` hook](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react#call-an-api)). My application doesn't use the hooks implementation, so I'm not able to dig into that part.

This is an example rule I just tested in my setup which let me read the context, authorization, and roles when logging in to my application. I tested using the "Real-time Webtask Logs" extension:

```
function (user, context, callback) {
  // This namespace can be whatever you want - it will be the 'key' that holds
  // an array of roles on the users token
  const namespace = 'http://anything.you.want';
  const assignedRoles = (context.authorization || {}).roles;
  
  console.log(context);
  console.log(context.authorization);
  console.log(assignedRoles);

  let idTokenClaims = context.idToken || {};
  let accessTokenClaims = context.accessToken || {};

  idTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;
  accessTokenClaims[`${namespace}/roles`] = assignedRoles;

  context.idToken = idTokenClaims;
  context.accessToken = accessTokenClaims;

  callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Then in my application I was able to see the role I added on my users token:

```
{
  ...
  "http://anything.you.want/roles": [
    "Test-Role"
  ],
  "given_name": "Ben",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-17T21:20:02.782Z",
  "email_verified": true,
  "iat": 1613596822,
  "exp": 1613632822,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately useAuth0().user is still unchanged. I have followed some docs https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/02-calling-an-api .... the code is similar to your example but they add a useEffect to display the metadata. BUT, the roles are not displayed UNLESS I manually add them  in the Dashboard > Users & Roles > Users > Details by using the 2 windows user_metadata and app_metadata. It makes no sense that I need to do this manually because I am trying to to get the values from the "Roles" association.

Answer (score 0):

For roles you need to add them to it yourself as far as I know.
In actions you can create a custom library:

See the following for how to set that up

https://auth0.com/docs/customize/actions/flows-and-triggers/login-flow#add-user-roles-to-id-and-access-tokens